# control arrowhead in Octave phasor plot

Tags: octave

I have an Octave script that plots phasors. The result is the top plot below.

How can I control the size & shape of the arrowheads to produce arrowheads more like you see in the 2nd plot below?

[image]

[image]

Below is my script code (I can't post it all because it violates some rule about too much code):

```
 for i = 1:length(phasors)
    % Calculate arrow head position and size
    arrow_x = real(phasors(i));
    arrow_y = imag(phasors(i));
    head_size = arrow_head_size * max_magnitude;

% Calculate the angle of the phasor
phasor_angle = angle(phasors(i));

% Calculate the angles for the arrow heads relative to phasor angle
arrow_head_angle_rad1 = phasor_angle + pi - deg2rad(arrow_head_angle);
arrow_head_angle_rad2 = phasor_angle + pi + deg2rad(arrow_head_angle);

% Calculate the positions of the arrow heads
arrow_head_x1 = arrow_x + head_size * cos(arrow_head_angle_rad1);
arrow_head_y1 = arrow_y + head_size * sin(arrow_head_angle_rad1);
arrow_head_x2 = arrow_x + head_size * cos(arrow_head_angle_rad2);
arrow_head_y2 = arrow_y + head_size * sin(arrow_head_angle_rad2);

% Plot arrow heads
plot([arrow_x, arrow_head_x1], [arrow_y, arrow_head_y1], 'Color', colors{i}, 'LineWidth', 1);
plot([arrow_x, arrow_head_x2], [arrow_y, arrow_head_y2], 'Color', colors{i}, 'LineWidth', 1);
```

end